# Getting data from multiple json in angular js

Tags: json, angularjs

How can I get the data from two JSON files, named gridData.json and AddedData.json simultaneously using $http.get function?

```
PApp.controller('ProjectDataController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.addProject=function($scope){

    };
    $scope.getData = function(){
        $http.get('AddedProjects.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.ProjectStat = data;
        });
        $http.get('JSON/gridData.json').success(function(data) {
            $scope.ProjectStat = data;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Please check. The code of the controller is given.

Comment: your code seems correct. only issue is that it uses the same scope variable. meaning one will overwrite the other

Comment: You might want to merge the objects...

Answer (score 1):

Better is to use two seperate variables on the scope. But if you have your reasons to keep it the same objects. You can merge them like below.

```
PApp.controller('ProjectDataController', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.ProjectStat = {};
    $scope.addProject=function($scope){

    };
    $scope.getData = function(){
        $http.get('AddedProjects.json').success(function(data) {
            angular.extend($scope.ProjectStat, data);
        });
        $http.get('JSON/gridData.json').success(function(data) {
            angular.extend($scope.ProjectStat, data);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: This code is giving me an error.

Error: dst is undefined extend@http://localhost:8080/ProjectCalendar/js/angular.js:406:7 $scope.getData/<@http://localhost:8080/ProjectCalendar/js/index.js:19:4 $http/promise.success/<@http://localhost:8080/ProjectCalendar/js/angu

Comment: check what is getting returned in data in both the cases.

Comment: I have solved it. By taking two separate $scope variables. I will let you know the return values.

Comment: On the clock of the button, the error is displayed. The function isn't even getting called.